# ERROR 1064 (42000) permissions

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> GRANT, SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX,
-> ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES
-> ON dbname.*
-> TO 'user'@'localhost'
-> IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
```

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX,
ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TA' at line 1

Been having this error on and off constantly lately and have no idea why.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this by removing the `comma ,` after the `GRANT`:-

```
mysql> GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX,
-> ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES
-> ON dbname.*
-> TO 'user'@'localhost'
-> IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
```

Comment: thanks fixed it but won't let me accept your answer for 8 minutes WTF

Comment: @CharlieBunt:- You are welcome. Not an issue, this is a feature of SO!(And thats really cool). You can accept it after the system allows you to do so :)

Answer (score -1):

No comma after `GRANT`:

```
mysql> GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX,
-> ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES
-> ON dbname.*
-> TO 'user'@'localhost'
-> IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
```